# Configuration with interface implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to somehow save below Configuration class into database as serialized JSON string. What would be the most proper way to serialize and then deserialize it (might use some intermediate class) to get Configuration class back with proper DataProcessor implementation.

```
public class Configuration
{
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
    public int Threshold { get; set; }
    public IDataProcessor DataProcessor { get; set;}
}

public class DataProcessorOne : IDataProcessor
{
}

public class DataProcessorTwo : IDataProcessor
{
}
```

Comment: What *proper* means here, what are the rules that bind an instance of `Configuration` to an instance of `IDataProcessor`? Please provide this context so that appropriate recommendation could be given.

Comment: @WiktorZychla By proper I mean the most elegant and flexible way. My first thought was to save exact IDataProcessor implementation as string (DataProcessorOne/DataProcessorTwo) and after fetching it from database get instance of provider from IServiceProvider by it's name.

Comment: Sounds like you should register the `IDataProcessor` as a factory function. In the factory you could retrieve the compiled binary from the database, cache it (so that it's not readed from the database upon subsequent requests) and load into memory (`Assembly.Load`) and then use reflection to create an instance of `IDataProcessor` from loaded assembly. This way an instance would be just injected into the `Configuration` by the Service Provider.

Comment: Why would you have Configuration depend on an instance of IDataProcessor in the first place? Seems backwards. Simplify this by removing that dependency. If Configuration is supposed to tell your app which IDataProcessor to use, then do so via a string.